# Kivy matplotlib -- How do I remove the extra white space

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, python-3.7

I have matplotlib inside my GUI in Kivy I'm using FloatLayout to place my widgets but when i add the plot inside my GUI it adds an extra white space to the left, so how do i remove that extra white space,I tried resizing it but it doesn't work nor does it respond to the size changes I try to make, any help will be appreciated.

If you don't have kivy-garden

[Start by installing kivy garden from here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html)

and then you run these commands in the cmd

```
pip3 install matplotlib
garden install matplotlib
```

This is my code below:

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
fig1 = plt.gcf()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='b', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

def autolabel(rects):
# attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., 1.05 * height, '%d' %
        int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.draw()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = FloatLayout()

        fig = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())

        fig.size_hint_x = 0.5
        fig.size_hint_y =0.5
        fig.pos_hint={"x":0.32, "y": 0}
        box.add_widget(fig)
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

This is the sample run i want to remove the extra white space on the left

[image]

Comment: this is really weird and might be something specific to kivy garden. I would probably take a shortcut and draw a black widget on top, which is not a nice solutio, but must work.

Comment: What I have seen is that when you increase its position at x the white space also increases, but what i tried is setting its position at x to zero which made the white space to disappear, which is not really nice now it allows you to only change its position at y.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a bug in necessarily, but I can at least see where the white space is coming from. In the FigureCanvasKivyAgg.draw() method, it is drawing a white rectangle before it does the figure texture map:

```
201        with self.canvas:
202            Color(*color)
203            # Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(w, h))
204            Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
205            self.img_rect = Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos,
```

Even though this first Rectangle instruction is being cleared when the canvas is being updated, say for an on_size event, there is apparently no further drawing instruction associated with on_size or other callbacks in the python module to fill that part of the canvas back in with black, or whatever the default color is. I commented out the Rectangle, and got the proper behaviour. Since I don't know the real reason for the Rectangle though, it could be breaking something else.